# Azure devops xcode task hangs

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-devops, continuous-integration

running this task for my CI in AZDO
macos-13 microsoft agent, xcode 15.0, agent version: 3.227.1 (sometimes i get 3.227.2 but it's not correlated to the timeouts)
same xcodebuild command executed locally (with cleaned derived data) works fine
i am going nuts.... at my rope's end. please help

```
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: "Archiving IPA"
  inputs:
    script: 'xcodebuild -showsdks'
    actions: 'clean'
    configuration: 'Debug'
    sdk: ''
    xcWorkspacePath: 'mobile/mobile.xcodeproj'
    scheme: 'mobile staging'
    packageApp: true
    exportMethod: 'ad-hoc'
    signingOption: 'manual'
    signingIdentity: 'Apple Distribution: .....'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '....'
    teamId: '....'
    destinationPlatformOption: 'iOS'
    args: '-verbose'
    useXcpretty: false
```

it hangs randomly. it can run 2 times fine, 3rd it hangs. i have a 60min timeout for the pipeline and if i leave it like this, it still won't budge until it times out. an ok run usually takes 10min. last thing i see in console is

```
2023-10-15T13:00:48.9604720Z CompileAssetCatalog /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-erawnnainwlxhxbadsuelqkzpzoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/mobile\ staging/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/staging.app /Users/runner/work/1/s/mobile/mobile/Assets.xcassets (in target 'staging' from project 'mobile')
2023-10-15T13:00:48.9606750Z     cd /Users/runner/work/1/s/mobile
2023-10-15T13:00:48.9632920Z     /Applications/Xcode_15.0.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-erawnnainwlxhxbadsuelqkzpzoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/mobile\ staging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/mobile.build/Debug-iphoneos/staging.build/assetcatalog_dependencies --output-partial-info-plist /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-erawnnainwlxhxbadsuelqkzpzoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/mobile\ staging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/mobile.build/Debug-iphoneos/staging.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist --app-icon AppIcon-Debug --compress-pngs --enable-on-demand-resources YES --development-region en --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --minimum-deployment-target 15.0 --platform iphoneos --compile /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-erawnnainwlxhxbadsuelqkzpzoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/mobile\ staging/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/staging.app /Users/runner/work/1/s/mobile/mobile/Assets.xcassets
```

this is as verbose as i think it can be

In a good run, what comes after the above is

```
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3891370Z /Users/runner/work/1/s/mobile/mobile/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon-Debug.appiconset/[][iphone][57x57][][][1x][][][]: notice: 57x57 app icons only apply to iPhone apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3896470Z /Users/runner/work/1/s/mobile/mobile/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon-Debug.appiconset/[][iphone][57x57][][][2x][][][]: notice: 57x57@2x app icons only apply to iPhone apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3901860Z /Users/runner/work/1/s/mobile/mobile/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon-Debug.appiconset/[][ipad][50x50][][][1x][][][]: notice: 50x50 iPad spotlight icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3904840Z /Users/runner/work/1/s/mobile/mobile/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon-Debug.appiconset/[][ipad][50x50][][][2x][][][]: notice: 50x50 iPad spotlight icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3908040Z /Users/runner/work/1/s/mobile/mobile/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon-Debug.appiconset/[][ipad][72x72][][][1x][][][]: notice: 72x72 app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3910810Z /Users/runner/work/1/s/mobile/mobile/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon-Debug.appiconset/[][ipad][72x72][][][2x][][][]: notice: 72x72@2x app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 7.0
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3913600Z /Users/runner/work/1/s/mobile/mobile/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon-Debug.appiconset/[][ipad][76x76][][][1x][][][]: notice: 76x76@1x app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 10.0.
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3915240Z /* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3917430Z /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-erawnnainwlxhxbadsuelqkzpzoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/mobile staging/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/staging.app/AppIcon-Debug60x60@2x.png
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3921270Z /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-erawnnainwlxhxbadsuelqkzpzoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/mobile staging/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/staging.app/AppIcon-Debug76x76@2x~ipad.png
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3924970Z /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-erawnnainwlxhxbadsuelqkzpzoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/mobile staging/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/staging.app/Assets.car
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3928780Z /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-erawnnainwlxhxbadsuelqkzpzoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/mobile staging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/mobile.build/Debug-iphoneos/staging.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3931100Z 
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3931170Z 
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3932020Z SwiftDriver staging normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'staging' from project 'mobile')
2023-10-15T12:49:45.3932980Z     cd /Users/runner/work/1/s/mobile
2023-10-15T12:49:45.4020840Z     builtin-SwiftDriver -- /Applications/Xcode_15.0.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -module-name staging -Onone -enforce-exclusivity\=checked @/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-erawnnainwlxhxbadsuelqkzpzoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/mobile\ staging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/mobile.build/Debug-iphoneos/staging.build/Objects-normal/arm64/staging.SwiftFileList -DDEBUG -D STAGING -sdk /Applications/Xcode_15.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.0.sdk -target arm64-apple-ios15.0 -enable-bare-slash-regex -g -module-cache-path /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options -enable-testing -swift-version 5 -I /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-erawnnainwlxhxbadsuelqkzpzoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/mobile\ staging/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-erawnnainwlxhxbadsuelqkzpzoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/mobile\ staging/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-erawnnainwlxhxbadsuelqkzpzoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/mobile\ staging/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks -F /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mobile-erawnnainwlxhxbadsuelqkzpzoi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/mobile\ staging/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/PackageFrameworks -F 
...............more rambling like this
```

PLEASE help :(

Comment: Please use Xcode 14 on macOS-12 and check whether there is the same issue or not. Currently, macOS-13 is [in beta](https://github.com/actions/runner-images#beta) and hasn't been released to GA, it may have some issues.

Comment: sorry but that  has to be a joke... we're at macos 14 and the previous version is still in beta? also, i can't use xcode 14... because of compiled frameworks. anyways, i think i figured it out. the issues is some images in the asset catalog (probably being single scale but having @3x in the name? or anyways.. it's some images... which is very silly because on a real mac it builds just fine

Comment: The purpose of a Beta is to collect feedback on an image before it is released to GA. The goal of a Beta is to identify and fix any potential issues that exist on that image. Customers choosing to use Beta images are encouraged to provide feedback in the runner-images repo by creating an issue. You can create an issue to file a bug report, or request tools to be added/updated from [How to Interact with the Repo](https://github.com/actions/runner-images#how-to-interact-with-the-repo).

Comment: Ok, It's year later, no longer in beta but performance still sucks at exactly this step.